# How to get around the "Under Attack" mode from Cloudflare on websites using requests?

Tags: c#, .net, dotnet-httpclient, cloudflare

I'm trying to achieve some web scraping to get information off of a website. The scraping code works great, however when the site gets thrown under load, Cloudflare activates it's "Under Attack" mode. This then returns a 503 error every time I try to scrape the site.

Is there any way to get around this? I've tried looking around on the site, and the current posts seem to be outdated, as the solutions are no longer functioning. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: So, the protection is actually doing what it's suppose to do? I doubt there's a good way to achieve that. I'm not sure based on what indicators cloudflare decides that an attack is going on, maybe using a different IP works. Also, is that your site? In that case you should have the option to turn that feature off.

Comment: @imsmn It isn't my website so I unfortunately don't have access to such a thing. From my understanding, it seems like the site attempts a JavaScript challenge for your request/browser and I'm not sure if there's a way to solve the challenge and return the response to the site using requests.

Comment: It sounds like you're really pounding this website while scraping.  You have a few methods of circumventing this:

You could reach out to the owner and inform them of your intentions.  They would be able to put you on a form of whitelist.

Or, you could limit the number of requests you are sending.  This will slow down your scraping but it will look less suspicious to Cloudflare.

Be sure to check the sites TOS to ensure you're within your rights.  Anything else is unethical and possibly illegal.